# Is [language-agnostic] a real topic?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) a real topic?

From the tag wiki:

> Use this tag for PROGRAMMING QUESTIONS that are independent of any particular programming language.

I can see what they were trying to get at with this, but this really seems like a "meta tag" to me more than an actual topic (or, at least, an exceptionally non-descriptive catch-all tag). Can you actually be an expert in "language-agnostic"?

With that said, I'm not sure exactly what to do with it. Should the tag be burned completely? Should questions with the tag be retagged? Does this tag need a large-scale cleanup effort anyway?

Comment: Is a language tag like [c#] or [javascript] a topic?  The vast majority of questions in those tags have nothing to do with the language.  The asker merely indicates his preference for the kind of solution he likes.  Somewhat inevitably there needs to be a way to indicate that he has no preference.

Comment: I don't see why there should be a tag for what a question **isn't** instead of only tags for what the question is. "language-agnostic" means not related to a language => what the question isn't. Furthermore, looking at the 1st page of questions with this tag, none seem to be relevant - some should have [algorithm] instead and some have [language-agnostic] together with a language tag?! (E.g. [c++], [java]).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Covering language-agnostic topics is well in scope and on-topic, given that we allow questions which involve algorithms and data structures, and those aren't necessarily tied to any one language.  The tag may be a wee bit overreaching given that language-agnostic concepts, such as algorithms and OOP enjoy well-scoped tags here already.

I'm *queasy* at the thought of sending the community in to do "cleanup" without you defining what cleanup effort you want to see, since we'd wind up with a ***mess*** if this were done improperly.

So...let's [start with a query instead](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/709698/find-questions-with-the-language-agnostic-tag) of all of the questions which *only* have the language-agnostic tag.  You're sure to find some really bad questions here, and these should be dealt with *first*.  Editing out the tags won't do any good since they'd be left untagged, and it would be tough to amass lots of delete votes on this.  But, I figure if we work our way through that simpler list, then it becomes *slightly* easier to justify its burnination.

Comment: I think the "language-agnostic topic**s**" bit is exactly the problem, though; if you're covering a language-agnostic topic, why not just tag it with the specific topic you're asking about (instead of some generic meta tag that doesn't describe what you're actually asking about at all)? For example, if you're asking about algorithms, we have an algorithm tag, so why not just use that? We also have a [data-structures] tag. I don't see how adding [language-agnostic] gives you any additional information about the content of the question.

Comment: Another issue: would you be any more likely to know about a language-agnostic data structures question than just a plain old data structures question? I don't see how the tag could possibly be helpful in finding questions that someone would be interested in answering or reading, which is the entire point of having tags in the first place.

Comment: @EJoshuaS:  My issue is that you haven't exactly described where we should start, given how sizable that tag is.  7K+ question is...not a quick-and-dirty burnination; it requires actual thought and actual digging to see if there's anything there of value.  My isolation of the questions exclusively tagged with it gives us a place to at least start removing garbage.  I don't disagree with the points you're making, but if you want a good burnination effort, then we need a good place to start attacking.  The ***last*** thing we want is for bad edits to come about as a result of this.