# What to do with this very old off-topic question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-delete, old-questions

I'm asking specifically about this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214357/how-to-make-a-living-by-programming-from-home

Image for under 10K if it ends up being deleted:
[image: question screenshot]

The question is very clearly off-topic (it's about general career advice) as well as primarily opinion-based.

Also, it's the only remaining question with the [remote-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remote-working) tag; it has no other tags and doesn't seem to fit very well with other tags.

With that said, the information is (arguably) potentially useful (even if off topic here). It's almost 9 years old at this point; it has almost 112k views, 93 favorites, and a score of 117.

Given that it's closed and that its most recent activity was 10 months ago, you *could* argue that it's not causing all *that* much harm (other than preventing the [remote-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remote-working) tag from going away).

Should this be left alone, deleted, or possibly re-tagged and locked as having historical significance but not representing a good, on-topic question? (I'd kind of prefer the latter option myself).

Comment: Can you save it? No? Sink it.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, I do agree that it's irredeemably off-topic.

Comment: First 2 lines from the privs page: *When should I delete questions? Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be flagged and deleted.*  So you have to ask, do we lose value if we delete this?  It is already closed so it is not going to cause harm.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, that was my thinking - it probably wouldn't be the end of the world to have it stick around, and it's apparently been useful to *someone* given that it's received a lot of views and upvotes (although it's worth noting that only approximately 0.1% of the views resulted in an upvote). The main harm it's causing is that it's the last remaining [remote-working] question, but that can probably be solved by re-tagging. I was having trouble figuring out what to re-tag it as, though, since it's so obviously off-topic.

Comment: The tag issue should be able to be solved.  I don't know if we can have a tagless question but if not there should be something we can through it into.  With ~12K views per year I'm hesitant to delete it.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I'd be reluctant to see it deleted too because the fact that people are still reading it suggests that people are looking for information on that topic. My thought was something like [language-agnostic] - it's not exactly on topic for that tag, but it's not strictly on-topic for *any* tag and [language-agnostic] is already terrible tag anyway IMHO (b/c it's too vague and [not a real topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354935/is-language-agnostic-a-real-topic)).

Comment: Remember that views and votes are a historical indicators. In the last two years, it accumulated <1 upvotes/month. The biggest chunk of votes was on '09

Comment: Would it be appropriate for Workplace SE?  Maybe it could be migrated?

Comment: @silencedmessage No, it's probably too broad. Also, [we don't migrate old or answered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: @Dukeling Such an old question can't be migrated even by a moderator anymore, can it? Wouldn't it have to be migrated by someone on staff if it was migrated at all?

Comment: @EJoshuaS "Wouldn't it have to be migrated by someone on staff" - yes, that's what the post I linked says. "After 60 days, migrations can only be performed by Stack Exchange employees. These are performed only in very, very rare procedural cases and are usually not done on request."

Comment: @Dukeling Sorry, I misread your comment - I thought when you said that "we don't migrate old or answered questions" you meant that we *could* migrate it (but we just don't).

Comment: But it's an almost 9 year old question about working from home / being self-employed. Things have changed quite a lot since then and what might have seemed like a challenge back then is pretty mainstream today. I see the question is pretty much irrelevant no matter where it is placed, if you have the guts to let go of corporate employment just do it. The projects are out there, LinkedIn likes to remind me of that on a daily basis :/ In other words: just nuke it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Vote for un-deletion and a historical lock.

I've voted to undelete it and vote that we ask for a historical lock. Whilst it's off topic, it's a helpful and interesting for remote programmers and that's why we have the historical lock. There's no point having it if we don't use it. Besides it shows the patchwork of our history that created this site and brought it to what it is now.

Comment: That would be my preference too, actually. I don't necessarily think that we should delete every off-topic question. (I unfortunately can't cast undelete votes yet, though, because I have less than 10K rep).

Answer (score 8):

This question is unquestionably irredeemably off-topic. It is also too old to migrate to any other site. Therefore, we have two options:

1. Delete the question entirely, using a strict application of our guidelines. This would result in the permanent loss of the information from the Internet, breaking any links that may point to the question and preventing anyone except 10k+ users from ever seeing it again.
2. Get a moderator to historically lock the question, which would forever preserve its contents in a locked state. This would allow anyone to find and view the question along with its answers, but no voting, editing, or any other actions would be possible. The benefit of this is that it preserves the availability of the information and avoids breaking any links; the downside is that it essentially locks in information that risks becoming completely obsolete because it can no longer be maintained. (However, if the information eventually loses all value, a moderator can still delete a locked question.)

So…what does the community want to do here? As it stands now, it's accumulating delete votes, which is fine, except some of our users don't have sufficient privileges to cast delete votes, and worse, no one has the ability to cast "preserve" votes to counter the delete votes, which has historically resulted in controversial questions continually being deleted/undeleted in an undesirable cycle. I would prefer that we come to a consensus here on Meta, expressing opinions by voting in a civilized way.

Comment: I can't see (or cast) delete or undelete votes (unless someone wants to award me bounties on a lot of my answers ;) ), so I guess I can't directly vote on that, but my thought is to lock it as being of historical significance. Given its high number of views, I'd be a little reluctant to get rid of it completely.

Comment: And now it's accumulating un-delete votes.

Comment: Sadly, this meta question does not seem to have attracted enough attention for a consensus to form. Unless something changes, option 3 (cycling through deletion and undeletion) is what will probably happen.