# Can we remove the HTC tag from many of the Android questions, instead of deleting them?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, closed-questions, burninate-system

There's a current burnination happening for the [htc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htc).

[Should we burninate the [htc] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351225/should-we-burninate-the-htc-tag)

There's [currently 141 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bhtc%5D%20%5Bandroid%5D%20is%3Aquestion) with both the [htc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htc) and [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

For Android developers, troubleshooting particular devices is relevant and helpful to have on the site. It's something that will continually pop up over time, with specific devices not behaving the way most devices do. The device tag does not need to be added, but can easily be included in the title to assist search results.

Can we please not remove these in bulk from the site, and instead just remove the [htc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htc)?

**Examples**

This type of question is only relevant to Android development. Being able to debug on devices is a necessary part of Android development.
[Android: ADB Driver for HTC One X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11012944/android-adb-driver-for-htc-one-x)

This may not seem like a relevant question, but the OP wants to determine the technology behind this effect to be able to program it.
[Name of technique behind 3D effects like HTC one dimension plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210069/name-of-technique-behind-3d-effects-like-htc-one-dimension-plus)

Another trouble shooting device specific issue.
[HTC Desire X USB ADB doesnt find it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233779/htc-desire-x-usb-adb-doesnt-find-it)

There's nothing wrong with this question.
[Crash log on HTC Flyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882014/crash-log-on-htc-flyer)

or this.
[app crashes using HTC ONE but works fine on all other devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012958/app-crashes-using-htc-one-but-works-fine-on-all-other-devices)

Comment: Related (on an old question that was obviously off-topic but appeared to be useful to many people): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355109/what-to-do-with-this-very-old-off-topic-question

Comment: I don't think that we should necessarily delete all of the closed questions - "closed" doesn't necessarily mean "useless."

Comment: @EJoshuaS yes - but they are currently being closed so they can be deleted and many of them don't need to be closed at all - they're doing no harm. They were on topic when they were posted and still are.

Comment: It seems like most of the questions I've seen closed really were off topic, though (with some exceptions). I think that a bigger problem is that not everything that deserves to be closed also deserves to be deleted, so it might be worth coming up with questions that are off-topic but should get historical locks.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example where questions are closed (deleted is maybe more difficult)  where you feel this shouldn't be done so the HTC burninators can reflect on their action and adjust accordingly? Or is your question more a preemption and should be read as burnination advice?

Comment: As a first step I updated the burnination progress post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355241/578411

Comment: @rene I can get some examples, would that be better?

Comment: @YvetteColomb it would certainly help others to make better judgement calls. At least that works for me.

Comment: This is just a special case of the more general problem of overzealous deletion. Just because a question is off-topic is not, in itself, a reason to delete it. You have to also evaluate whether there is any useful content that would be lost as part of the deletion. If people have not been doing this when casting delete votes, shame on them.

Comment: @CodyGray exactly - the issue with these questions being closed with the tag included in the burn process is *they will be deleted*. Also I can see clearly that what the community views as ontopic for Android and what Android devs view as ontopic are two different things. There's many device specific bugs that devs need to troubleshoot, there's continuous changes with each sdk revision and sometimes code isn't even necessary - just a problem description and the sdk versions or the logcat - if it's device specific. But only someone who understands Android can differentiate these. to be cont..

Comment: .../ as with npe - there's some devices that will throw seemingly extraneous npes. And people will close them as dupes - but the code will need some work around that drives devs crazy searching the internet for and I've tried to address this on meta - my question was downvoted - and deleted by Community User. I know I'm just one small needle in the haystack, but I'm trying to help sort out some issues on the site - so we really can differentiate between what's useful and what's not. It's a huge issue I know. And restricting reviews and votes to tag experience will only hinder and clog .../

Comment: ..../  review queues. But  it would be good if we had some place - on meta where we can discuss specific tags - without the wider community jumping in - let the people who work in the tag in real life discuss it.

Comment: I agree there needs to be a better way in general to handle tagging-related issues: burnination, merges, synonyms, renaming, cleanups, etc. But I don't know what that is, so Meta's the best we've got. I'm sort of surprised to hear you making this argument now. When I've bellyached in the past about mass Meta-led burninations, I thought I remembered you being firmly on the other side. Oh well, maybe my memory is failing. At any rate, I don't know that the problem is the Android community vs. the world. I think it's just in the phrasing of those questions---they *seem* broad.

Comment: @CodyGray indeed I was, until the godaddy burn. After that I refused to participate in them, for all the reasons cited in this question. And I was at fault myself. I'm really pleased you are mod - it's giving me energy to try and make changes - I want to work with you and others active on here - to make the changes we want to see. I've learnt a lot participating on meta (*a lot from Hans Passant - though he doesn't know it*) - when my questions are downvoted - I reflect upon why and will usually see the other perspectives and rethink mine. So that's why you're surprised.

Comment: I think that the two caveats here are that a) standards should be uniform community-wide - I've seen tags where the vast majority of questions were off-topic, so the fact that people in that tag want to keep a particular kind of question doesn't necessarily mean that questions should get a free pass on site rules and b) I think that the only questions we should even be considering preserving are ones where there's proof that it's actually helping large numbers of people. For example, in the Meta post I linked to, the question being discussed had over 111k views and a score of 117...

Comment: ... so there was concrete evidence that many people considered it useful. As a hypothetical example, if a 2-year-old question has a score of 1 and maybe an upvoted answer or two, that wouldn't necessarily be adequate evidence that it should be preserved (because only one person found it useful enough to upvote, so if anything that would imply that it's *not* helping very many people).

Comment: @EJoshuaS it's not our job to just dispose of content that only has one or two upvotes. If it's on topic - it's ontopic. Just because it has a tag on it that is being burned - that doesn't automatically decide it should be deleted.

Comment: Frankly, it sounds like some tag which permits HTC to be indicated for android questions would be useful. Perhaps, as has been [suggested on the burniation question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351225/should-we-burninate-the-htc-tag#comment505054_351225), something like [[tag:htc-android]].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with this - I think that we need to be careful about which ones of these we delete. Actually, *most* of the questions I've seen in [htc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htc) should be retagged, not deleted, with the exception of a few egregiously bad questions that "slipped through the cracks" earlier.

Even some close-worthy questions shouldn't be deleted if there's evidence that they're useful (because we don't want to lose content) - my preference would be to historical lock useful but OT questions to prevent VLQ answers or people using them as evidence that they can ask similar questions.

I'm concerned that if we just delete all of these in bulk that some valuable content will be lost, so I'd be in favor of going through the closed questions and picking out some useful ones to historical lock and save before deleting all of them.