# Clean up [language-agnostic]

Tags: discussion, clean-up

This is a concrete proposal related to this Meta question: [Is [language-agnostic] a real topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354935/is-language-agnostic-a-real-topic)

I am proposing cleaning up the [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) tag in preparation for possible burnination. You can't really be an expert in [language-agnostic] - you really should use more descriptive tags. For example, if you're asking a language-agnostic data-structures tag, there's already a data structures tag. Questions with other useful tags like this can just have this tag removed without any harm.

Currently:
7,721 questions
51 unanswered questions with a scored of zero and no answers.
599 closed questions
698 questions who are only tagged with [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic), 575 of which are open

Many of the questions tagged only with this are polls, requests for lists of things, discussions, etc. For example, here's a sample of some of the questions (several of which are closed, and several of which aren't):

[Most harmful misconception of beginners about programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124968/most-harmful-misconception-of-beginners-about-programming)

[Dealing with the rate of change in software development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104890/dealing-with-the-rate-of-change-in-software-development)

[What's the difference between the open source licences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137100/whats-the-difference-between-the-open-source-licences)

[Should you worry about fake accounts/logins on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167835/should-you-worry-about-fake-accounts-logins-on-a-website)

[What is a good technique or exercise when learning a new language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139239/what-is-a-good-technique-or-exercise-when-learning-a-new-language)

One issue to resolve: some of those are cases like what was described in [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355109/what-to-do-with-this-very-old-off-topic-question), where there are popular but clearly off-topic questions. You also have cases like [Most harmful misconception of beginners about programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124968/most-harmful-misconception-of-beginners-about-programming), which currently has 4,812 views, 68 answers (accepted answer's score is +60/-2), and a score of 36. Granted, that's arguably not all *that* high for a question that's been around for over 8 years, but still, there are cases in those where we'd risk potential information loss (68 answers) or where, like in the other Meta post I linked to, the question was popular.

The question linked to in the Meta post I link to was retagged and then eventually deleted, but there doesn't seem to be a clear community consensus on what to do in cases like this. These can also be remarkably difficult to re-tag since they're so clearly off-topic. Would it be worth creating a separate Meta post specifically related to getting community consensus on the topic prior to a cleanup effort?

My proposal, then, is to start the cleanup effort by going through the questions that are only tagged with [language-agnostic].

We should also filter on the [language-agnostic] tag in the close vote queue to resolve all outstanding flags and close votes. Actually, this is something that people with less than 3K rep can help with a lot: the bulk of the work here will be identifying and flagging questions so that people can filter on it in the queue, so this is something that anyone who has enough privileges to send stuff to the close votes queue can help with a lot.

Comment: I *really* don't think that folks with less than 3K rep should be doing any of this.

Comment: @Makoto Not necessarily editing/retagging, but I think that they can play a much larger role in tag cleanup in general because a good part of the work is getting the right questions into the Close Vote queue.

Comment: It's [not recommended](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) for someone without full edit privileges to participate.

Comment: @Makoto That's true - for the editing part, they would normally need at least 2k so their edits can instantly apply without needing to go through the edits review queue. For identifying off-topic questions and putting them into the close vote queue, though, I think that anyone with flagging privileges can/should be encouraged to participate (because that's the part that you need a lot of manpower for, especially for a large tag).

Comment: uhdunno if this is a good idea... I've used LA in the past as a cesspool into which I throw questions that are off-topic and have had all their off-topic tags burninated.  That's the problem--questions have to have tags. Can't burninate a tag if it's on a question, and if it's the only tag relevant to the crap question (i.e., no relevant tag exists that can be substituted) then we can't burn the tag.

Comment: @Will I'm not sure I follow... if it's a cesspool of off-topic questions (which it is), why wouldn't we burn it? If we find a question that's so off-topic that it can't be retagged, I suspect that we'd probably want to close and delete it.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't burn a tag if it's on any question, including deleted ones. I may be incorrect (or it may have changed in the time since I've gone on burninations)...

Comment: As soon as you mentioned the expert argument you lost all support from me and I stopped reading your post entirely. That is not in any way whatsoever a metric for determining whether a tag should exist or not, never has been and I hope to god that it never will be.

Comment: @Will in cases where a tag is removed and it is the only tag on a question (using the CM tool), it is replaced with [tag:untagged]

Comment: @TinyGiant CM tool? I just verified I can't remove the last tag from a question or apply Untagged.

Comment: @Will there is a Community Manager only tool that does bulk removal of a tag from all questions containing that tag. When that tool meets a question that has only the one tag, it replaces that tag with [tag:untagged]. I don't remember how I came upon this information.